# Ubuntu Dual Monitor Problem

Tags: 13.04, multiple-monitors, external-monitor

My problem is when i start an app or something like that.
App starts on the extra monitor.
When i do options>display change sides with external monitor and laptop.
It fixes but i want external monitor on the left, laptop is on the right.
How can i fix that problem ?
Thanks...

Comment: Yes, i tried that.But apps still starting at external monitor.New downloaded/created files is going to external monitor.I just want laptop monitor as primary.How can i do ? Thanks.

Comment: Can't help you there, got the same problem on 12.04

Comment: Is there a chance for fix this problem ? :)

Answer (score 0):

In KDE there's a setting where you can set up a monitor for each application to be opened on startup. you can even set the exact position, heigth, width, workspace, ...

That's something I missed in other GUIs, too.

Comment: Can u tell me how can i do this ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Installing KDE:

```
sudo apt-get install kde-standard
```

wait for a long time until kde desktop environment is installed.
When you log in you can change the session to kde (or back to whatever you used to use when kde displeases you).
In the kde i don't exactly know the path of the configuration for the requested settings, but you can assign a position, a workspace... for any application start. KDE is very highly configurable but as all systems that are highly configurable it consumes large amounts of time to config it until it behaves as the user wants.